# AnyLogic 7: Imports failing after update to Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: anylogic

I updated to Mac OS X Yosemite this morning, and my models fail with the following error:

> *The import quicktime cannot be resolved*

which points to the following line within the Advanced Java section of one of my agents:

```
import quicktime.streaming.NewPresentationParams;
```

I don't even know how to begin troubleshooting this, since I can't tell where in AnyLogic any of the .jar files are, or anything else useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Was this an import you added, or one that comes default with AnyLogic? That'll change how you handle the problem. (Also, I see that someone downvoted this question; I presume it's a matter of the way you worded your description. Check out [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- very helpful! :) )

Comment: Thanks, Dylan.  It is a default AnyLogic import.

Comment: That's very peculiar. Can you describe your problem further? What Agent is causing the problem? What does the Agent's logic look like? Do you know where Quicktime might be used (e.g., are you using graphics, sound, or other media in your model)? Can you give us a stack trace (the red text your model spits out to the console when it dies)? Is there a Quicktime / video / media object from the palette you could drag into your model? (I ask the final question because I once had an import problem resolved by adding a palette item that would force the import.) Finally, have you contacted AnyLogic?

Comment: In reverse order:  1)  I have contacted AnyLogic.  They finally got back to me and had me reinstall Java.  Which now makes AnyLogic quit unexpectedly.  So I can't even get into my model any more.  2)  Stack trace will be attached once I can get AL to run again.  3)  It's a very basic agent, represented only by a rectangle that doesn't even change color.  It doesn't move, doesn't do anything fancy.  I wasn't importing quicktime in it at all.

Comment: That's very unfortunate and undoubtedly frustrating. What version of Java did you install? I'm not sure that older versions of AnyLogic can handle the newest versions of Java, but I could be wrong about that (I'm just another user, after all!). Knowing your Java version would be very helpful to AnyLogic and myself for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: They asked me to install Java 1.6.  And yes!  This is quite frustrating.  :)

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I just upgraded to 7.1 as well and am experiencing issues. Hopefully we get some feedback soon. :)